# Check if Tweets exist with Python using URLs

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweepy

I have over 1M tweets that I need to screen and I need to check if they have been deleted or not. And I have their URLs; is there a way to use Twitter API to check if the Tweets have been deleted or not? Also, I have the correspondent list of users; can I somehow check if they follow a certain user? Thank you very much.

Yeah, I tried to use `api.get_status()` and if it does not exist it will return

```
tweepy.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found
144 - No status found with that ID.
```

but then I don't know how to use this condition to eliminate the unqualified ones.

Comment: You can use TwitterAPI and urllib3 library in python:
For urllib3, if tweet isn't exist, response status equals 404.
TwitterAPI is like urllib3. Also, users can be controlled with TwitterAPI.
[urllib3 library](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3)
[TwitterAPI library](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the [new Twitter API v2 batch compliance endpoints](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-batch-compliance-endpoints-available-on-the-twitter-api-v2/158534).
[Tweepy v4.1.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.1.0) added support for these with [`Client.get_compliance_jobs`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_compliance_jobs), [`Client.get_compliance_job`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_compliance_job), and [`Client.create_compliance_job`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_compliance_job).

Otherwise, you can just handle the [`tweepy.NotFound`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/exceptions.html#tweepy.errors.NotFound) exception.

You can use [`API.get_friendship`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.get_friendship) to get the relationship between two users, including whether they follow one another.